# Return relationship data along with the new Model object when saving the new Model using the save() method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, save, eager-loading

```
$user = User::find(1);
$post = new Post();
$user->posts()->save($post);
```

I want to access the new `Post`'s `User` without making an additional query to the database. It queries the database for the `User` if I do the following:

```
$userPost = $post->user;
```

I'm aware I could just do `$userPost = $user`, but for certain reasons, I don't want to do it that way.

So my question is, would it be possible to eager load the `User` when saving the new `Post` with `save()`?

Comment: Does `$post->load('user');` work? It _would_ be an additional query, but why the restriction? A single `WHERE id = ...` query, as this would be, is not a performance hit (or shouldn't be; would be surprising if it was)

Comment: `$user->posts()->save($post);` will return newly created Post complete with id and timestamps , so I guess you can not do that , but you can do `$user->load('posts')` to reload only the relationship (extra query)

Comment: @TimLewis Instead of doing 2 queries, it's doing 3. That's a 50% increase. This particular piece of code will be running _many_ times daily, I want it to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: @Win I was hoping there would be a different method to save or a flag to return the `Post` with the relationship, being that it was created directly from it (`$user->posts()->save($post)`).

Comment: Well, you already have `$user`, so do `$post = Post::create(['user_id' => $user->id, ...])` (replacing `...` with the rest of the fields), then you can do `$post->user = $user`, and finally `return $post;`. That would be 1 query, and `$post->user` would be populated. But again, this query is not complex; many times daily shouldn't matter at all when this query would (should) take microseconds each time, and a 50% increase on microseconds is still microseconds 

Comment: Here is my question  Why?. .   if you are creating this post thing and have the user in a variable then just use that.  If you are not or don't have the user then you have no choice but to query the DB.     You could inject it with a custom method such as setUser($user) or in the constructor, and then populate the property yourself.  The downside is you should do a check of the user objects ID to see that it matches before changing the class property.  Because it would/could be possible to pass the wrong user in then.

Comment: I wouldn't do it for performance, but an issue you may have is working with two instances of the same record that are in different states.  For example if you have two copies of the user and change the email in one then save the other, that can be confusing to figure out sometimes. ( I just had something similar happen in wordpress )

Answer (score 0):

I just try the following way to save new post with minimal query.

```
$user = User::with('posts')->find(1);

// create new post , but not save it yet
$post = new Post(['title' => 'lorem ipsum', 'body' => 'something something']);

// push it to user posts collection
$user->posts->push($post);

// and now save it
$user->posts()->save($post);

// then check the content, post should now have id and timestamps
dd($user, $user->posts);
```

The new Post is there with id and timestamps, without need to reload all posts, saving you a bit performance and execution time.

One might asked, how many queries were executed?

1. "select * from "users" where "users"."id" = ? limit 1"
2. "select * from "posts" where "posts"."user_id" in (1)"
3. "insert into "posts" ("title", "body", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) returning "id""

I used `DB::enableQueryLog()` before transactions and `DB::getQueryLog()` after transactions to track these queries.

...

And regarding your question: `$post->user`.
**Unfortunately** this will still trigger *an extra query*.

`"select * from "users" where "users"."id" = 1 limit 1"`

---

Now lets compare to good old add post to user steps. (2nd option)

- `$id = 1;`
- `$user = User::with('posts')->find($id); // needs 2 queries`
- `$post = Post::create(['user_id' => $id, 'title' .... ]); // 3rd query`
- `$user->load('posts');` // 4th query (but this is optional)
- `$userPost = $post->user; // and last query`

In total will need to execute 4 or 5 queries, depend on do you need to load all posts as user's children.

In term of performance, cpu usage and execution time are almost the same, with the 1st steps above is a bit faster in execution time.

So at the end it is back to you.
What do you really need in the system you are currently building?
Keep the $user->posts with new post added, that choose 1st.
But if you just want directly to catch $userPost, than use 2nd option.

*Note:* no need to use `$user = User::find($id)` if you already know that user $id is exists.

Comment: While this works, I think you're still missing the point... How does this answer the question of *"would it be possible to eager load the `User` when saving the new `Post`"*? `$post->user` is not eager loaded with this approach...

Comment: I test it using DB::queryLog and in total there were only 3 queries, 1st => select from user by id 1 , 2nd => select all posts related to user id 1 , and last query 3rd => insert post returning id ... does this not qualified as eager loading ?

Comment: It does, but you're eager loading the "wrong direction"; `$post->user` is not eager loaded, but `$user->posts` (the inverse/other direction) is, by way of `$user->posts->push($post)`. If you were to call `$post->user->id` for example, that would execute another query (as would `$post->load('user');`). In my comment above, I suggested assigning vs eager loading, like `$post->user = $user` (after `new Post() ... ->save()`, or `Post::create()`, etc.), which would bypass eager loading by direct assignment. There's nothing wrong with your answer per-se, it's just backwards 

Comment: aha @TimLewis , thanks for noticing , I forgot to add `with()` on user find, i just copied Carlos code. that is why queries executed were only 3 , thanks again for noticing.

Comment: @TimLewis , apologize to bother you , if you can test this eloquent steps at your end , how many queries were executed ? is there possibility using DB:queryLog() is not the best solution to track queries , can you point out any other mean to track queries ? thanks in advance